# Error while installing Zeek-aux : Unknown CMake command "FindRequiredPackage"

Tags: zeek

I've downloaded the zeek-aux zipped source-code from 'https://github.com/zeek/zeek-aux'.
While comipiling i'm getting the following error.

'Unknown CMake command "FindRequiredPackage"'

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A ZIP download from GitHub doesn't populate the git submodules, and the functionality you're missing is defined in the cmake submodule. You can verify this by doing an `ls` in the `cmake` directory -- there's likely nothing in there.

You can fix this in a few different ways. The easiest likely is to use a recursive clone instead of a ZIP download: `git clone --recursive https://github.com/zeek/zeek-aux`. Alternatively, you can stick with the ZIP and say `git submodule sync --recursive` followed up `git submodule update --recursive --init` in its toplevel directory.